# HTML5 card game

Tags: javascript, layout, knockout.js, html5-canvas, playing-cards

I created a card game in silverlight a year or so ago in order to learn a bit about Silverlight.

I am now wanting to make a HTML5 version of the game in an effort to learn a little bit more about that.

I am thinking I'd like to take advantage of stuff like Knockout.js and WebSockets and the `canvas` element.

Now what I'm confused about is how to lay out the cards on the screen.

With Silverlight I was able to make a "Hand" control, which was made up of two sub controls - the cards the player has in their hand and the ones they have on the table. And they in turn were made up of Card controls.

Now I don't believe there is the concept on a User Control in javascript. So I am possibly thinking about this in entirely the wrong way.

So my question is - how could I lay out some cards on the table and perhaps make reuse of something for each player?

I have a client side JSON object called game, which contains an array of players. Each player has a hand which is made up of an array of in-hand cards and on-table cards. Ideally I would like to bind these to something  using Knockout.js - but I don't know what I could bind to.

Would I simply position images (of cards) on a canvas? Is there a way to make some kind of Hand object that each player could have and that I could bind to?

Any advice? Or sample code you've seen elsewhere?

Comment: I feel that the way your question is phrased is too specific to your particular problem. If you could generalize it a bit, and provide some sample code, it would fit on SO much better.

Comment: Nice question, but hard to answer without any sample code.  Can you post what you have done so far on http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I guess it is quite vague - but that's because I know nothing about HTML 5 ! All I have so far is some code to get the JSON data. Just trying to work out how I can display that data. I'm not really looking for someone to correct my code - more get some ideas of what HTML5 offers in this regard

Comment: There is no such concept of user controls in JavaScript, but you can make instances of constructor functions and fetch appropriate data of those instances. So you could make a `Card` constructor whose instances represent cards, as well as a `Hand` constructor whose instances represent the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no view construct such as XAML or DOM in the canvas. With canvas you are literally drawing lines, fills, images, and such with really basic functionality. You will need a canvas library to find, or more probably build, the types of controls you mention. See [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) for a possible canvas library candidate.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a single canvas for rendering the game I would probably use a canvas per card and then layout them using CSS.

If you decide to choose this route you'll need to figure out how to sort out selections, possible dragging etc. This should be easy compared to doing all that on a single canvas though since in this case you can rely on vanilla JS and CSS.

If you can provide some kind of visual mockup I can probably give you some more specific pointers.

Comment: Or just images (or more likely a `div` with `background-image` and make a CSS sprite). I can't really see why you'd want to use a canvas.

Comment: That's definitely true. I guess canvas might come in handy in case he generates the card images procedurally. Even in that case it might make sense to do that somehow else.